# PHP: Is it safe to auto include every file in a folder

Tags: php, wordpress, security

Is it considered a security vulnerability to automatically include every php file within a specific folder ?

I am developing a WordPress theme framework that I will use on various projects, I want to be able to create modules for this theme as separate files so that each project can have their own modules. I want to be able to simply drop a module into a folder and it will work.

Below is content of the **init.php** file which gets included in the main theme class. It works great, I just want to make sure there are no obvious concerns in my approach:

```
foreach (scandir(dirname(__FILE__)) as $filename) {
    $path = dirname(__FILE__) . '/' . $filename;
    if (is_file($path) && $filename != 'init.php' && substr($filename, -4) == '.php') {
        require_once($path);
    }
}
```

Comment: As a developer, especially one who develops code that will end up being used by others, it's been my observation that if anything can go wrong it will. If somebody can do something backwards, sideways, or upside down, they will. You should definitely use some sort of filename prefix if you're going to go with this approach, and ensure that the filenames are checked before including them.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't consider this a security issue, this is basically what composer is doing too.
But you should make sure that nothing writes to this folder during runtime of you application which could break it.